# Statically build and linking with CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, static-libraries, libcurl, static-linking

I'm trying to wrap my head around statically linking c++ applications using CMake.

I have built `libcurl` statically:

```
./buildconf
./configure --disable-shared --with-openssl
make -j$(nproc)
make install
```

Which produces a static `/usr/local/lib/libcurl.a`:

```
$ ldd /usr/local/lib/libcurl.a
        not a dynamic executable
```

My CMake is configured to build and link statically:

```
include(CMakePrintHelpers)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)

project(static-build-test)

set(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES ".a")
set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS OFF)
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-static")

find_package(CURL REQUIRED)
cmake_print_variables(CURL_LIBRARIES)

add_executable(static-test main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(static-test PRIVATE ${CURL_LIBRARIES})
```

But my build fails to link with many "undefined reference to" errors:

```
$ make
Scanning dependencies of target static-test
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/static-test.dir/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable static-test
...
url.c:(.text+0xf6): undefined reference to `idn2_free'
md5.c:(.text+0x6a): undefined reference to `MD5_Init'
openssl.c:(.text+0x29a): undefined reference to `SSL_set_ex_data'
...
```

My static build for `libcurl.a` completed without error but still fails to link with my application due to these undefined references. Why doesn't the static library for libcurl include the static libraries it depends on (openssl, etc.)?

I presume I need to find all these missing references and track down their static libs as well. Is it that I need to link ALL of these libraries directly to my final executable?

Comment: "Is it that I need to link ALL of these libraries directly to my final executable?" - yes, if a static library has its own dependencies, those must be linked to your artifact as well, as well as _their_ dependencies, and so on, transitively, until the whole DAG has been resolved.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any difference, then, to linking statically or shipping a binary with all the required dynamic libraries next to it (in the executable directory, for example)? Other than having 1 executable vs an executable with a lib/ next to it.

Comment: Static libraries do not link with other libraries, so libcurl does not include the libraries it depends on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For libraries, like CURL, that have first-class CMake package support, you should use it. Here is how I linked to CURL statically.

First, we download and build CURL:

```
$ git clone git@github.com:curl/curl.git
$ cmake -G Ninja -S curl/ -B _build/curl -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=NO
$ cmake --build _build/curl
$ cmake --install _build/curl --prefix _local
```

After this, we can write the *correct* CMakeLists.txt, which only links to imported targets. Notice that this build uses *no variables*.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23)
project(test)

find_package(CURL REQUIRED)

add_executable(static-test main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(static-test PRIVATE CURL::libcurl)
```

And now we can build this, pointing CMake to our freshly built CURL package, via `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`:

```
$ cmake -G Ninja -S . -B _build/test -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=$PWD/_local
...
-- Found CURL: /path/to/_local/lib/cmake/CURL/CURLConfig.cmake (found version "7.85.0-DEV")  
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /path/to/_build/test
```

and now we can run the build and see that all of the required libraries are there:

```
$ cmake --build _build/test --verbose
[1/2] /usr/bin/c++ -DCURL_STATICLIB -isystem /path/to/_local/include -O3 -DNDEBUG -MD -MT CMakeFiles/static-test.dir/main.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/static-test.dir/main.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/static-test.dir/main.cpp.o -c /usr/local/google/home/reinking/test/main.cpp
[2/3] : && /usr/bin/c++ -O3 -DNDEBUG  CMakeFiles/static-test.dir/main.cpp.o -o static-test  ../../_local/lib/libcurl.a  -ldl  -lpthread  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so && :
```

As you can see, curl and its transitive dependencies, `dl`, pthreads, openssl, libcrypto, and libz, all appear correctly on the link line.

Comment: Thanks. Here `static-test` still links dynamically to libz.so, libcrypto.so, libssl.so, etc. To make a completely portable `static-test` I will need to link directly to those static libraries as well?

Comment: You will need to build CURL against static versions of those dependencies. You cannot link together a static and shared version of the "same" library in one application.